# Scan CSV to variables

Tags: matlab, variables, csv

I have a CSV like this (one line):

```
101, 120, 130
```

How can I scan these into variables like this:

```
pt_num = 101
x = 120
y = 130
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`csvread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html):

```
M = csvread('filename.csv');
pt_num  = M(:,1);
x = M(:,2);
y = M(:,3);
```

You can also use `textscan` to get each column in a cell array:

```
fid = fopen('filename.csv','r');
C = textscan(fid,'%d, %n, %n');
fclose(fid);
```

And there is `fscanf`, but you will have to reshape the array:

```
fid = fopen('filename.csv','r');
M = fscanf(fid,'%d, %f, %f')
fclose(fid);
M = reshape(M,3,[])';
```

Finally, `dlmread`, which works just like `csvread`:

```
M = dlmread('filename.csv',',');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm coming from C and was hoping there was something like this: fscanf (file, "%d %lf %lf", &pt_num, &x, &y).  I'll be scaling up to larger matrices.  Any other possibilities?

Comment: @Ben This will work for any number of lines. Notice the colon syntax in `M(:,1)` that gets all values in the first column.  However, there is a `fscanf` in MATLAB if you want to go that route, this is just easier.