# Specify decimal separator for .dat file in matlab

Tags: matlab

I've got a bunch of .dat files, where the decimal separator is comma instead of dot. Is there any function in MATLAB to set comma as the separator?

Comment: How are you going to read those files into Matlab?

Comment: @lnk The referenced "duplicate" suggests to use some third-party `txt2mat` program, which is probably serious overkill. See my answer for a simple way of converting the text data you have read into a cell array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to read the data in as text (with `textscan`, `textread`, `dlmread`, [etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20154448/2778484)) and convert to numeric.

Say you have read the data into a cell array with each number in a cell:

```
>> C = {'1,2345','3,14159','2,7183','1,4142','0,7071'}
C = 
    '1,2345'    '3,14159'    '2,7183'    '1,4142'    '0,7071'
```

Use `strrep` and `str2double` as follows:

```
>> x = str2double(strrep(C,',','.'))
x =
    1.2345    3.1416    2.7183    1.4142    0.7071
```

---

For your example data from comments, you have a file "1.dat" formatted similarly to:

```
1,2 3,4
5,6 7,8
```

Here you have a space as a delimiter. By default, `textscan` uses whitespace as a delimiter, so that is fine.  All you need to change below is the format specifier for the number of columns in your data  by repeating `%s` for each column (e.g. here we need `'%s%s'` for two columns):

```
>> fid = fopen('1.dat','r');
>> C = textscan(fid,'%s%s')
C = 
    {2x1 cell}    {2x1 cell}
>> fclose(fid);
```

The output of `textscan` is a cell array for each column delimited by whitespace. Combine the columns into a single cell array and run the commands to convert to numeric:

```
>> C = [C{:}]
C = 
    '1,2'    '3,4'
    '5,6'    '7,8'
>> x = str2double(strrep(C,',','.'))
x =
    1.2000    3.4000
    5.6000    7.8000
```

Comment: So, I have file 1.dat which contains:

Comment: two rows:1,2 3,4 '\r'5,6 7,8 I want to obtain matrix M=[1.2 3.4; 3.4 7.8;]. With function csvread('1.dat') I obtain: 1 2 3; 4 0 0

Comment: @lnk As the name implies, `csvread` uses commas as a delimiter between values, so you do not want to use that function. Use `textscan` instead, see updates answer.

Comment: @lnk Can you accept the answer if this did what you needed? Thanks. :)

Comment: Just today figured out how to accept answers))