# how to perform string to double in matlab using delimiter

Tags: string, matlab

I have 1x14 char output

```
A = '   3691/1784  '
```

What I want to get is

P = 3691

Q = 1784

I have tried the following as explained in another answer 
here:[Specify decimal separator for .dat file in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555743/specify-decimal-separator-for-dat-file-in-matlab)

```
output=str2double(strrep(P,'/','.'))
```

But the output is 3612.1784.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You mean `output=str2double(strrep(A,'/','.'))`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
output = str2double(regexp(A, '\d+', 'match'));
```

Or, if the numbers may contain a decimal part,

```
output = str2double(regexp(A, '\d+(\.\d*)?', 'match'));
```

Comment: Didn't know `str2double` converts a cell array of strings to an array of doubles.

Comment: @A.Donda Yes, it's very handy for that

Answer (score 1):

Using `strsplit` and `deal`:

```
output = deal(str2double(strsplit(A,'/')))
```

Might be overkill for this case but that's an alternative haha