# reading decimal number with GUI matlab

Tags: matlab, text-files

I am developing a user interface using matlab wich allows to browse and load a text file and  display some curves. I am facing a problem, my file text is a set of decimal number, matlab is reading those number as two columns. 
this is an exemple: u find here the file that I am working on:

[image]

After runing this code :

```
[filename pathname] = uigetfile({'*.txt'},'File Selector');
fullpathname = strcat(pathname,filename);
text = fileread(fullpathname); %reading information inside a file
set(handles.text6,'string',fullpathname)%showing full path name
set(handles.text7,'string',text)%showing information
loaddata = fullfile(pathname,filename);
xy = load(loaddata,'-ascii','%s');
t = xy(:,1);
i = xy(:,3);
handles.input1 = i;
handles.input2 = t;
axes(handles.axes1);
plot(handles.input1,handles.input2)
```

the curves looks so strenge, so I checked the result of xy= load(loaddata,'-ascii') using command window and here the problem appears!

[image]

So I have now 12 columns instead of 6 ! can u help me please? 
I tried with strrep(data,',','.') but it doesnt work !

Comment: So your question is about parsing the file? How about you post the *actual* file contents and show only the relevant lines of code. This has nothing to do with a GUI.

Comment: Hello, I edited my question now to make it more clear u can check it please :)

Comment: Can you paste the actual data into the question rather than posting a screenshot?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specify decimal separator for .dat file in matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555743/specify-decimal-separator-for-dat-file-in-matlab)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using commas, for your radix point, you will want to first load in the entire file as a string, replace the `,` with `.` and then you can use `str2num` to convert the entire file to a numeric array

```
% Read the entire file into memory
fid = fopen(loaddata, 'rb');
contents = fread(fid, '*char')';
fclose(fid);

% Replace `,` with `.`
contents = strrep(contents, ',', '.');

% Now convert to numbers
data = str2num(contents);
```

Comment: @EmnaAmeur If that worked for you, consider marking it as a solution