# Can't Visualize Ascii File on Matlab

Tags: matlab, ascii

I have  .txt file created by an STM32 connected to a accelerometer sensors.
This file are Ascii file (probabily 8bit)

I tried to visualize on Matlab using

```
 ZZ = load('000_LOG.TXT', '-ascii')
 Error using load
 Unknown text on line number 1 of ASCII file 000_LOG.TXT
```

so i tried

```
 zx = load ('000_LOG.TXT')
 Error using load
 Unknown text on line number 1 of ASCII file 000_LOG.TXT
```

so i  tried after reading this post [importing ASCII file to Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20154005/importing-ascii-file-to-matlab)

```
  fid = fopen ('000_LOG.TXT');
  >> myData = fread ('fid') 
  Error using fread
  Invalid file identifier. Use fopen to generate a
  valid file identifier.
```

The command "importdata" worked, but i can't convert to dec

```
  Xw = importdata ('000_LOG.TXT')

  Xw = 

             '|}}|}}|~}|~}|~}|}~|}~}}~}}~}}}}}~}}~}}|}}}}|}|}}~}}}}}}}|€}|}|€}}€}|...'
```

In fact

```
 Wx = bin2dec(Xw) 
 Error using bin2dec (line 35)
 Binary string must be 52 bits or less.
```

This is the link to the file .txt on dropbox
https://www.dropbox.com/l/s/mDoDk5puIpZaEdLth4w0Lr

Thanks for your support

Comment: Your use of `fread('fid')` is wrong... it should be `fread(fid)`.  Also the text file is written in ASCII and after those sets of characters, it looks like each triple of characters is an 8-bit digit.  Because you didn't write this as a binary file, this is going to be even more difficult to parse. You'll have to read in the raw text then write code to convert each triple of characters into their equivalent decimal representation.  I think you should go back to the documentation of your accelerometer and figure out how the data is being outputted, then come back and ask a question.

Comment: @rayryeng i am an idiot. I corrected the error that you noticed and the problem was solved. Now I can visualize and plot my data. Thanks for all.